# SQL query for fetching latest entry for ID1

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a schema with following attributes:

1. ID1
2. ID2
3. Update Date Time

The primary key of this schema is {ID1,ID2}. I need to find a the value of ID2 for a given ID1. There will be multiple values for ID2. I need the one with latest time which I can fetch using "Update Date Time".

I have a list of ID1's for which I need to find the corresponding ID2's in one query.

I can do it, using two queries. First of all grouping by ID1 and fetching the max Date Time for the ID1. And then fetching the ID2 for that "date Time" value(We can assume "Update date Time" is unique for all entries).

But I was thinking if it is possible to do this is in a single query.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is `MYTABLE`,  I have used a subquery to fetch the `ID2` value with `MAX(UPDATED)` for each `ID1` value. The `ID1` values are passed as comma separated values, shown as `LIST_OF_ID1s`.

The query below should do just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE T1 where T1.ID1 in (LIST_OF_ID1s)
AND T1.ID2 = 
 (SELECT T2.ID2 FROM MYTABLE T2 
  where T1.ID1 = T2.ID1 
  ORDER BY T2.UPDATED DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Working SQL Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4df1/3/0)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    SELECT t0.ID1,t0.ID2,t0.Update_date_time
    FROM table AS t0
    LEFT JOIN table AS t1 ON t0.ID1=t1.ID1 AND t1.Update_date_time>t0.Update_date_time
    WHERE t1.ID1 IS NULL;
```

done in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e3879/8/0

Comment: what if there are 3 or 4 options?

Comment: @sagi what you mean 3 or 4 options? if there are id3 and id4 you just select them out it won't impact anythings as long as you want group by ID1 and compare the update date time if you mean multiple update_date_time  then you may need row_number to do this

Comment: Old school. Nice - but slower than the more modern methods documented in the manual

Comment: Yes i meant multiple update date time, because there are, he said it.

Comment: @sagi no i don't think he said it i didn't see how he want deal with another datetime type column to choose the latest or the earliest, if you met situation like that you just use rownumber partition by id1 and order by multiple time columns. but it can't be done in 1 simple query at least you need 1 subquery

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke thats what he asked for, he said there could be many ID2 for the same ID1, so you need rownumber, and yes it does demand a sub query like i posted above.

Comment: @sagi you can check the link of fiddle i give upon. many ID2 doesn't matter this query is just fine, like strawberry said it's old school and effect, you could just go try it, it's 1 simple query no subquery in my opinion when you use subquery it doesn't count for 'a single query'

Comment: @sagi Rownumber partition is some other dialect, so irrelevant here - but I completely disagree that a subqueried is not a 'single query'. That's simply wrong.

Comment: @sagi oh, and when i said row_number, its for the situation like this: you have ID1,ID2,Updatetime,CreateTime and you want get the lastest UpdateTime and the earliest CreateTime.

Comment: @Strawberry oh, i'm not deny subquery i just think you can do this in 2 queries like the author said he can first group by with ID1 to get the max datetime then match the id2, you can simple done this with subquery just make the first query as subquery using where exists could solve this problem. but that won't help right?